# Calculate 14-day rolling average on data with two hierarchies

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the 14 day rolling average for retail data with multiple different hierarchies. The 'Store' dataframe looks like this:

```
Store  |  Inventory-Small  |  Inventory-Medium   |   Date  |   Purchases-Small  |   Purchases-Medium
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  A            12                   14              4/1/20         2                      4
  B            13                   16              4/1/20         4                      5
  A            15                   10              4/2/20         2                      6
  C            20                   15              4/1/20         4                      5 
  A            16                    8              4/3/20         2                      4 
  A            16                   10              4/4/20         4                      5
  A            15                   12              4/5/20         1                      3 
  C            18                   14              4/2/20         2                      3
  C            19                   12              4/3/20         6                      9
  B            14                   14              4/2/20         3                      8
```

What I am trying to do is create a rolling 14 day average for the purchases column for each store. The data extends well past 14 day (over 8 months), and I would like the first 14 days of each store to be a simple average. My issue is that while I can group by 'Store' and create a column, I don't know how to also group by dates. I've tried:

```
Store.sort_values(['Store','Date'],ascending=(False,False))
Store['Rolling_Purchase_S'] = Store.groupby(['Store','Date'], as_index=False)['Purchases-Small'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(14, 1).mean())
```

and also:

```
Store['Rolling_Purchase_S'] = Store.groupby('Store')['Purchases-Small'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(14, 1).mean())
```

The first one doesn't seem to have any effect while the second one doesn't group by dates so I end up with a rolling average in the wrong order. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Edit: The following lines worked, thanks to all for the feedback.

```
Store.sort_values(['Store','Date'],ascending=(False,True),inplace=True)
Store['Rolling_Purchase_S'] = Store.groupby('Store')['Purchases-Small'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(14, 1).mean())
```

Comment: If ordering is your problem, isn't grouping the wrong thing to use to solve that?  I would think you'd only want to group by Store, and then you'd want to sort by Date somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's working fine as long as you sort *inplace* and remove 'Date' from `groupby`:

```py
Store.sort_values(['Store','Date'], ascending=(False,False), inplace=True)
Store['Rolling_Purchase_S'] = Store.groupby(['Store'])['Purchases-Small'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(14, 1).mean())
```

Output:

```
print(Store[['Store', 'Date', 'Purchases-Small', 'Rolling_Purchase_S']])
  Store       Date  Purchases-Small  Rolling_Purchase_S
8     C 2020-04-03                6            6.000000
7     C 2020-04-02                2            4.000000
3     C 2020-04-01                4            4.000000
9     B 2020-04-02                3            3.000000
1     B 2020-04-01                4            3.500000
6     A 2020-04-05                1            1.000000
5     A 2020-04-04                4            2.500000
4     A 2020-04-03                2            2.333333
2     A 2020-04-02                2            2.250000
0     A 2020-04-01                2            2.200000
```

Comment: @Max Couto Silva Thanks for the advice. I did need to sort inplace=True and remove 'Date' from groupby. I also needed to sort the date by descending to get the correct average.

Comment: Yeah, it depends how you want to calculate the rolling average. It's by descending order, I think you meant by `ascending=True`, which is the default (so you don't need to specify `ascending` at all). Best!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things to point out but you're very close. I changed a couple items to make it work. To illustrate the sorting, I modified the first date for each store to 4/10

If your dates aren't datetime, the sorting may not work as expected. also, you need inplace=True to make the change permanent

```
input = '''Store Inventory-Small Inventory-Medium Date Purchases-Small Purchases-Medium
A 12 14 4/10/20 2 4
B 13 16 4/10/20 4 5
A 15 10 4/2/20 2 6
C 20 15 4/10/20 4 5
A 16 8 4/3/20 2 4
A 16 10 4/4/20 4 5
A 15 12 4/5/20 1 3
C 18 14 4/2/20 2 3
C 19 12 4/3/20 6 9
B 14 14 4/2/20 3 8'''

Store = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(input), sep=' ')
Store['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Store['Date'])
Store.sort_values(['Store', 'Date'],ascending=(True, True), inplace=True)
Store['Rolling_Purchase_S'] = Store.groupby('Store')['Purchases-Small'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2, 1).mean())
```

Also, I changed the timeperiod to 2 because I had little data to work with, it'll need to go back to 14 for your dataset

Output:

```
In [137]: Store
Out[137]:
  Store  Inventory-Small  Inventory-Medium       Date  Purchases-Small  Purchases-Medium  Rolling_Purchase_S
2     A               15                10 2020-04-02                2                 6               2.000
4     A               16                 8 2020-04-03                2                 4               2.000
5     A               16                10 2020-04-04                4                 5               3.000
6     A               15                12 2020-04-05                1                 3               2.500
0     A               12                14 2020-04-10                2                 4               1.500
9     B               14                14 2020-04-02                3                 8               3.000
1     B               13                16 2020-04-10                4                 5               3.500
7     C               18                14 2020-04-02                2                 3               2.000
8     C               19                12 2020-04-03                6                 9               4.000
3     C               20                15 2020-04-10                4                 5               5.000
```